# Django reset_sequences doesn't work in LiveServerTestCase

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I've updated django from 1.6 to 1.8.3.  I create test models in test setUp method in unit tests, something like that

```
class MyTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    reset_sequences = True
    def setUp(self):
        self.my_model = models.MyModel.objects.create(name='test)
```

And I have code in the application, which relies on the primary key == 1. I've noted, that sequences aren't actually reseted. In each next test the pk is greater, that in previous.

This works ok in django 1.6, but after migration to 1.8 problems appears.

Should I reset sequence manually?

P.s. I know about fixtures, but my models are more complicated and for me it's easier to create models in the code.

Comment: are you using teardown method? Usually its used to "clean up" the stuffs created into setUp method.

Comment: No, because as far as I understand, the django roll back the database  to post_migration state. And in the tests I don't see any data from other tests, just the single model, but with increasing pk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in sqlite3. The tests have been run with other settings file, where sqlite3 is configured as database.

The django checks, if the database supports sequences:

```
# django.test.testcases.py:809
def _reset_sequences(self, db_name):
    conn = connections[db_name]
    if conn.features.supports_sequence_reset:
        sql_list = conn.ops.sequence_reset_by_name_sql(
            no_style(), conn.introspection.sequence_list())
    # ....
```

So I've switched test settings to the postgresql and now it works normally