# Running Django unittests on PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to switchover a Django unittest suite to use PostgreSQL as its backend. Changing the Django test settings was finally trivial, but now I'm getting a lot of subtle errors when the tests load fixtures. After hours of tinkering, I found the problem was because Django's not resetting the id counters on the tables, so even though all rows are deleting from each table between tests, all new fixtures don't use the Id's in the fixture but instead us an Id that's 1 plus the maximum Id used in the last test.

Very frustrating. So I dug through the code to see why this was happening, and if it was a bug in my usage of Django 2.2, and I found the `django.test.TransactionTestCase` even has a nifty little `_reset_sequences()` method for resetting all table sequences between tests.

However, I'm using the standard `django.test.TestCase`, and for some reason, in the `_fixture_setup()` method, it explicitly disables `_reset_sequences()` and assert an error:

```
AssertionError: reset_sequences cannot be used on TestCase instances
```

if you try to call it. Why is this?

As is, Django's failing to reset table counters, and is breaking my unittests. Why can't table sequences be reset in the standard TestCase?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31609818/1526703